# Can I map a wrap a simple object with a class?

Tags: typescript

I'm looking to mapping an object to a class, maybe my technical wording is wrong so I'll try and illustrate.

```
var car = {wheels:4, color:"red", maxSpeed: 100}

class Car(){
    wheels: number;
    color: string;
    maxSpeed: number
}

let wrappedCar = new Car(**car)
console.log(wrappedCar.wheels)
// 4
```

What's the best way to achieve this in Typescript? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this be OK for you?

```
var car = { wheels: 4, color: "red", maxSpeed: 100 }

class Car {
    wheels: number;
    color: string;
    maxSpeed: number
}

let wrappedCar = <Car> car
console.log(wrappedCar.wheels)
```

---

The proper solution to do this would be using a constructor and merging the Objects:

```
var car = { wheels: 4, color: "red", maxSpeed: 100 }

class Car {
    wheels: number;
    color: string;
    maxSpeed: number

    constructor(carObj) {
        for (var a in carObj) { this[a] = carObj[a] }
    }
}

let wrappedCar = new Car(car)
console.log(wrappedCar.wheels)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is this called `type casting`? Do you think it would be possible to have some code run when the casting is performed?

Comment: Yes thats typecasting, but remember it wont have anything else that you define in the class that is not in the object

Comment: Ah that means functions will be missing as well! Did I get that right?

Comment: yes, I added an option using a constructor. this will work

Comment: But why would you create two objects? Just use the signature `constructor(wheels, color, maxSpeed)`.

Comment: @Louy I think he already has this object and wants to convert it to a class object? Well but we dont realy know why he is doing this indeed

Comment: You're right. Maybe just add that as a suggestion :)

Comment: @RadiantHex can you explain what you want to achieve? We could help you better then

Comment: @CodeiSir @Louy thanks guys! The objects I'm using have about 87-92 properties, I'd like to wrap these in a class without a long `this.argN = argN; ...` constructor, while adding the remaining class logic on top.

Comment: @RadiantHex Ah OK, the best way to do this would be `for (var a in carObj) { this[a] = carObj[a] }` (see modifeyed answer) - You have to copy the attributes / merge the object into the classObject.

Comment: @CodeiSir d'oh, that's perfect :)

Comment: @RadiantHex OK, test if it works for you. If not feel free to ask again, otherwise I would appreciate if you accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is describe an objects structure you can use an **interface**.

It would be something like this

```js
interface Car {
  wheels: number;
  color: string;
  maxSpeed: number
}
```

You can later just use it normally.

```js
let car: Car = {
  wheels: 4,
  color: "red",
  maxSpeed: 100
}
```

The compiler will also automatically recognize if an object implements that interface. So you it's perfect for describing what you expect to receive in your methods.

```js
function washCar(car: Car): void {}

washCar({
  wheels: 10,
  color: 'red',
  maxSpeed: 100
}); // will work

washCar({
  name: 'John',
  age: 5
}); // will generate a compilation error
```